# Making the right choice between node.js and ape server

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, real-time, ape

Im at a stage where i need to decide between the two

- Node.js
- Ape server

Ive heard great opinions about both but im a bit confused myself.
I need to do a lot of realtime stuff so which would be a good option?
I hear node.js with socket.io is great and
ape has a lot of cool demos on their website

I will also need to create a bigpipe system for a fast interface like facebook has.
So which will be good?
Im really confused and i dont see ones advantage over the other so i would like some advise here

And for node.js to work with mysql i need to have extra drivers and stuff so yeah.
Advise is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You said: "Ive heard great **opinions** about both". The site FAQ says: "not constructive: This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. ...this question will likely solicit **opinion**..."

Comment: What I'd do is read up about both, and if you have a specific, measurable aspect you'd like to compare objectively, you can post about that here.

Comment: If you just want more opinions, you are also free to ask for them in SO chat.

Comment: One final note: Instead of commenting to correct yourself ("Sorry I meant ..."), you can click the "edit" link under your post and make the actual change.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax Push Engine (APE) Vs Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304589/ajax-push-engine-ape-vs-node-js)

Answer (score 4):

One of the important things about deciding on a new technology is the availability of support for that technology. If it is the greatest, most elegant technology in the world, but there is only one guy who knows how to use it, then you probably shouldn't go with that technology.

That being said, there are over 7000 node.js questions tagged on stackoverflow and only 48 questions tagged with ape. Now maybe the APE developers have their own community somewhere, but that still indicates that it's not a large enough pool of users to reliably get help when you need it. That alone would have me leaning **heavily** towards Node.JS and Socket.IO.

Here is another question about the same thing: [Ajax Push Engine (APE) Vs Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304589/ajax-push-engine-ape-vs-node-js)